# click() doesn't work in IE 11 but works in Chrome on the same elements

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have two clickable elements on my webpage, which is a login page. One is a remember-me checkbox, and the other is a login button. The code below executes successfully on chrome. However, when I run the test against IE 11, the tests actually pass! But the buttons are never clicked. Only the 'will recieve a login error' test fails with IE because the error message is never presented since the login button is never clicked.

Here is the code:

```
//run test
describe('Test my Login webpage', function () {

var usernameInput = element(by.id('UserName'));
var passwordInput = element(by.id('Password'));
var loginButton   = element(by.tagName('button'));


it('will open the login webpage', function () {
browser.get('http://<my website>/Account/Login');
});

it('will click the remember-me checkbox', function () {
    expect(element(by.id('RememberMe')).isSelected()).not.toBeTruthy();
    element(by.id('RememberMe')).click();
});

it('will type a username', function () {

    expect(element(by.id('UserName')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    usernameInput.sendKeys('testing...').then(function () {
        expect(element(by.id('UserName')).getText()).toBe('');
    });
});

it ('will type a password', function () {
    expect(element(by.id('UserName')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

    passwordInput.sendKeys('fakePassword').then(function () {
        expect(element(by.id('Password')).getText()).toContain('');
    });
});

it('will click login button', function () {
    expect(loginButton.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    loginButton.click();

    browser.waitForAngular();

    usernameInput.clear();
    usernameInput.sendKeys('my second attempt');
});
it('will recieve a login error', function () {
    expect(element(by.css('.error-msg')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    //expect(element(by.class('error-msg')).getText()).toMatch('Username or password was invalid, please retry');
});
});
```

Comment: what selenium webdriver version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting an explicit wait in before you .click().  IE is notorious for being slower to load objects, and thus more synchronization is needed.

Comment: I have a few more suggestions: 1) Make sure that protected mode is on (I have seen this do some odd things, when its not set) with IE 2) Try using a 32 bit driver if your not already (java script can have some issues with the 64 bit driver).  Please reply back if either of those helped

Comment: It's currently on, after it was off. Either ways, the .click() function didn't work. I am using the 32 bit driver, because the 64 bit driver is extremely slow.